# XMPP GCM Android implementation guidance

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, chat, openfire

I have been working on GCM xmpp implementation for my chat functionality, but about a week, I am not getting online help to start with , I have got this [XMPP GCM Android tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/), but I see xmpp is not fully implemented, and upon seeing their code, it is very unclear to understand the functionality

firstly. my current structure is

1. Android client app for chat functionality.
2. java backend, app server jboss hosted in openshift cloud platform.

and according to this google gcm-xmpp image.. I see client interacts directly to gcm, which I get confused, intern gcm connects app server.

[image]

as per my implementation, I get gcm regid from gcm and send http request to app server which intern send notifications to client devices through gcm. this is reverse of what we see with gcm flow diagram

secondly, since I have already set up app server Jboss, which can handle http request for my client request other than chat functionality. now I need to implement xmpp for handling asynchronous, bidirectional, upstream messaging with another servers like openfire or ejabberd which supports xmpp.

currently I am in state where I don't know how to start with xmpp, I have got above queries, in the hope getting some directions to start with.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826148/android-gcm-understanding-xmpp/33834899#33834899. Hope that explains things!

Comment: @KayAnn your link is really helpful thx